# How to clip multiple shapes in one shape in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I want to achieve this in illustrator but the solution I see is CTRL+7 which work only for one shape... In photoshop, you just need you clip as many as you want...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply copy the large circle -- <kbd>Ctrl/Commad</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>

Select None -- <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>

Paste in in front -- <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>

Select All -- <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>

Create a clipping mask -- <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd>

Comment: Thanks~ Also, I've found...
- Group the 2 small circle
- then clip them